# Testing series for divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(2(n+1))- \ln(2n)$$

How can I test it to show it is divergent?

Comment: $$\ln(2(n+1))-\ln(2n)=\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)$$ and, after that, Cauchy's condensation criterion and $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k=e$$

Comment: If you want to be formal about things, show that $\lim \ln(1+1/n)/(1/n)=1$. and use limit comparison. To show that the limit is $1$, maybe write $t=1/n$ and recognize that $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}$ is a derivative.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** "Telescoping series."
This is of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n+1}-a_n)$, with $a_n \to \infty$.

---

Or, more heavy and complicated:
$$
\ln(2(n+1))- \ln(2n) = \ln \frac{n+1}{n} = \ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}
$$